Send tansactional email using Mailchimp in Laravel after order purchased
Send Email To Customer as soon as he purchase the product. Here is the code sample
$response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode('apikey:' . env('MAILCHIMP_TRANSACTIONAL_APIKEY')),
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ])->post('https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/messages/send', [
        'message' => [
            'subject' => 'Purchase Confirmation Email',
            'from_email' => 'info@imperialinternet.com',
            'to' => [
                ['email' => $customerEmail],
            ],
            'html' => view('emails.purchase_confirmation', compact('orderDetails', 'products'))->render(),
        ],
    ]);


And here is my html code for email
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Purchase Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Purchase Confirmation</h1>
    <p>Dear {{ $order['firstName'] }} {{ $order['lastName'] }},</p>
    <p>Thank you for your purchase!</p>
    
    <h2>Order Details:</h2>
    <p><strong>Order ID:</strong> {{ $order['orderId'] }}</p>
    <p><strong>Total Amount:</strong> ${{ $order['totalAmount'] }}</p>
    <!-- Include other order details here -->

    <h2>Business Details:</h2>
    <p><strong>Business Name:</strong> {{ $order['businessName'] }}</p>
    <p><strong>Business Nature:</strong> {{ $order['businessNature'] }}</p>
    <!-- Include other business details here -->

    <h2>Customer Details:</h2>
    <p><strong>Customer Email:</strong> {{ $order['customerEmail'] }}</p>
    <p><strong>Customer Phone:</strong> {{ $order['customerPhone'] }}</p>
    <!-- Include other customer details here -->

    <h2>Product Details:</h2>
    @foreach ($products as $product)
        <p><strong>Product Name:</strong> {{ $product['productName'] }}</p>
        <p><strong>Product Price:</strong> ${{ $product['productPrice'] }}</p>
        <!-- Include other product details here -->
    @endforeach

   
</body>
</html>

I want that my laravel 9 code send custom email to customer as soon he purchased the product i have mailchimp api key and i want a transactional email.

Try using the notifications in Laravel.

I have solved this issue. Thanks
